# Acceptable Method for Bonding Metal Pool Fence

Tags: code-compliance, pool, bonding

I'm in Dutchess County, New York and we are installing an aluminum pool fence similar to one shown in the picture below. The fence is within 5 ft of the pool edge along three sides and further than 10 ft away on the remaining side. The electrician says he is required by code to bond each individual post along the entire perimeter of the fence on all four sides. This seems overkill to me since the metal of the fence is essentially all connected, so that attaching a bonding wire anywhere along the fence would pick up current generated anywhere else along the fence. I could see a requirement to bond in a few places, say each corner, etc. -- but all 30 posts? Would appreciate any specific rules or code regulations that would be applicable here. Thank you.

[image: pool fence]

Comment: Pools and electricity have killed a lot of people, which is how they get lots of special treatment in code, to prevent killing more. Aluminum forms an insulating oxide coating on exposure to air, and the colored coating may also be insulating, so good electrical conductivity between parts is hardly assured.